# How using historical local package on a laravel 10 project using vitejs instead of laravel-mix?

Tags: laravel, package, laravel-livewire, alpine.js, laravel-10

I have an historical laravel project and I upgrade it from 5 to 8.

Now I want to create some others features and to do this I want to start with a fresh laravel 10 instance.

The historical project use vuejs and typescript.

For the new project I want to use livewire and alpineJS instead of vuejs and I'm not really fond of typescript so I don't want to use it.

I started create this new project but I'm facing a problem with local packages.

The historic project use some locals packages to deal navigation, notification and admin panel.

I have to precise that the new project using vitejs to compile assets instead of laravel mix in the historical project.

The package that deal the navigation works fine but it doesn't contain javascript.

The notification package doesn't work and it uses some javascript.

**The directory tree of the package :**

```
packages
└── web    
    └── notification
        ├── src
        │   ├── assets
        │   │   └── js
        │   │       └── notifications.js
        │   ├── lang
        │   │   └── fr
        │   │       └── notifications.php
        │   ├── views
        │   │   └── notifications.blade.php
        │   ├── Notification.php
        │   ├── NotificationFacade.php
        │   └── NotificationServiceProvider.php
        └── composer.json
```

**notifications.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Handle the notifications panel
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    var $notifications = $('#notifications');

    $notifications.find('.close-btn').each(function (index, element) {
        var $closeButton = $(element);
        var $notification = $closeButton.closest('div[class^="notification-"]');

        $closeButton.click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            close();
        });

        function close() {
            var $element = $notifications;

            if ($notification.siblings().length > 0) {
                $element = $notification;
            }

            slideUp($element);
        }

        function slideUp($element) {
            $element.slideUp(400, function () {
                $element.remove();
            });
        }
    });

});
```

**notifications.php**

```php
<?php
return [
    'error'     => 'Erreur',
    'success'   => 'Succès',
    'info'      => 'Information',
    'warning'   => 'Attention',
];
```

**notifications.blade.php**

```
@if ($notifications)
    <div id="notifications">
        @foreach ($notifications as $type => $messages)
            @if ($messages)
                <div class="notification-{{ $type }}">
                    <a href="#" class="close-btn icon-remove"></a>
                    <h4>{{ $types[$type] }} :</h4>
                    @foreach ($messages as $message)
                        - {{ $message }}<br />
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
```

**Notification.php**

```php
<?php
namespace Web\Notification;

use Illuminate\Session\Store;
use Illuminate\View\Factory as View;
use Illuminate\Translation\Translator as Lang;


class Notification
{

    protected $lang;
    protected $view;
    protected $session;
    protected $messages = [];


    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Session\Store $session
     * @param View $view
     * @param Lang $lang
     */
    public function __construct(Store $session, View $view, Lang $lang)
    {
        $this->lang = $lang;
        $this->view = $view;
        $this->session = $session;

        $this->messages = $this->session->get('notifications', []);
    }


    /**
     * Add messages to the session
     *
     * @param string|array $messages
     * @param string $type
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function add($messages, $type)
    {
        foreach ((array)$messages as $message) {
            if ($this->isUnique($type, $message)) {
                $this->messages[$type][] = $message;
            }
        }

        $this->session->flash('notifications', $this->messages);

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * Determine if a type and message combination already exists
     *
     * @param string $type
     * @param string $message
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function isUnique($type, $message)
    {
        $messages = $this->messages;

        return !isset($messages[$type]) OR !in_array($message, $messages[$type]);
    }


    /**
     * @param string|array $messages
     * @return Notification
     */
    public function success($messages)
    {
        return $this->add($messages, 'success');
    }


    /**
     * @param string|array $messages
     * @return Notification
     */
    public function info($messages)
    {
        return $this->add($messages, 'info');
    }


    /**
     * @param string|array $messages
     * @return Notification
     */
    public function error($messages)
    {
        return $this->add($messages, 'error');
    }


    /**
     * @param string|array $messages
     * @return Notification
     */
    public function warning($messages)
    {
        return $this->add($messages, 'warning');
    }


    /**
     * Test if there are messages to output
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isEmpty()
    {
        return empty($this->messages);
    }


    /**
     * @param string $type
     * @return array
     */
    public function get($type)
    {
        return isset($this->messages[$type]) ? $this->messages[$type] : [];
    }


    /**
     * @param bool $flush
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAll($flush = true)
    {
        if ($flush) {
            $this->flush();
        }

        return $this->messages;
    }


    /**
     * Forget any notification in the session
     */
    public function flush()
    {
        $this->session->forget('notifications');
    }


    /**
     * Render your notifications
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function render()
    {
        $this->flush();

        return $this->view->make('notification::notifications')
            ->with('notifications', $this->messages)
            ->with('types', $this->lang->get('notification::notifications'));
    }

}
```

**NotificationFacade.php**

```php
<?php
namespace Web\Notification;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;


class NotificationFacade extends Facade
{

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    { 
        return 'notification';
    }

}
```

**NotificationServiceProvider.php**

```php
<?php
namespace Web\Notification;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;


class NotificationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('notification', function($app) {
            return new Notification($app['session.store'], $app['view'], $app['translator']);
        });
    }


    public function boot()
    {
        $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__ . '/views', 'notification');

        $this->loadTranslationsFrom(__DIR__ . '/lang', 'notification');
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__ . '/lang' => resource_path('lang/vendor/notification'),
        ], 'lang');

        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__ . '/assets' => resource_path('assets/vendor/web/notification'),
        ], 'assets');
    }

}
```

On the older project I also have a typescript file :

**resources/js/support/notify.js**

```
class Notify {
    removeDuration = 500
    notificationElements = []
  
    static getInstance() {
      if (!Notify.instance) {
        Notify.instance = new Notify()
      }
  
      return Notify.instance
    }
  
    addSuccess(message, hideClose = false) {
      return this.add("success", message, hideClose)
    }
  
    addError(message, hideClose = false) {
      return this.add("error", message, hideClose)
    }
  
    addWarning(message, hideClose = false) {
      return this.add("warning", message, hideClose)
    }
  
    addInfo(message, hideClose = false) {
      return this.add("info", message, hideClose)
    }
  
    remove(notification) {
      if (!notification) {
        return
      }
  
      notification.style.height = notification.offsetHeight + "px"
      notification.style.transitionProperty = "height"
      notification.style.transitionDuration = this.removeDuration + "ms"
      notification.style.height = notification.offsetHeight + "px"
      notification.offsetHeight // Redraw element
      notification.style.height = "0"
  
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        this.container.removeChild(notification)
        this.notificationElements.splice(
          this.notificationElements.indexOf(notification),
          1
        )
      }, this.removeDuration)
    }
  
    has(notification) {
      if (!notification) {
        return false
      }
  
      return this.notificationElements.indexOf(notification) >= 0
    }
  
    constructor() {
      this.container = document.querySelector("aside.c-notify")
  
      // Get existing notifications from server
      let notifications = JSON.parse(this.container.dataset.notifications)
      Object.keys(notifications).forEach(key => {
        this.add(key, notifications[key])
      })
      this.container.removeAttribute("data-notifications")
    }
  
    add(type, message, hideClose = false) {
      if (!Array.isArray(message)) {
        message = [message]
      }
  
      let notification = document.createElement("div")
      notification.classList.add("notification")
      notification.classList.add("notification-" + type)
      if (hideClose) {
        notification.classList.add("no-close")
      }
      notification.innerHTML =
        `<div class="wrapper">` +
        `<a class="close icon-error" href="#"></a>` +
        message.map(value => `<div class="message">${value}</div>`).join("") +
        `</div>`
      notification.querySelector(".close").addEventListener("click", event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        this.remove(notification)
      })
  
      this.container.appendChild(notification)
      this.notificationElements.push(notification)
  
      return notification
    }
  }
  
  export const notify = Notify.getInstance()
```

Notifications are render using this `{!! Notify::render() !!}` in the layout.blade.php file.

And the notificication creation using this

`Notify::success(trans('controllersMessages.loggedOut'));`

or

`throw ValidationException::withMessages([trans('controllersMessages.mustAcceptCGU')])->redirectTo(URL::route('site.auth.register-client'));`

in controllers.

I tried to convert notify.ts to notify.js and compiling assets like this :

**vite.config.js**

```
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

var config = {
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/sass/app/appMaster.scss', 
                'resources/sass/admin/adminMaster.scss',
                'resources/sass/errors/errorsMaster.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
                'resources/js/support/notify.js',
                'resources/assets/vendor/webl/notification/js/notifications.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
            
        }),
    ],
    build: {
        assetsDir: '',
    },
    server: {
        hmr: {
            host: 'localhost',
        },
    }

}

export default defineConfig(({command, mode, ssrBuild}) => {
    if (command === 'serve') {
        config.publicDir = 'public';
        config.build = {
            assetsDir: '',
            copyPublicDir: false,
            emptyOutDir: true,
        };
    }

    return config;
});
```

I have no errors when compiling and no errors on browser, just notifications doesn't display.

I'm new with vitejs and I'm wondering if the package can works on a laravel 10 instance...
Do you think it would be possible?

I'm open at a new way to avoid using this package and dealing notifications for example with livewire and alpineJS.

I tried following this tutorial (https://fly.io/laravel-bytes/global-notifications-with-livewire/) but I failed to make it work on my project...

I'm listening your advices...

Thanks